# updating wx.Gauge and keep current frame alive?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I am writing a little tool that downloads file from a website using python and `wxpython`.

I have got everything working, the only thing's been bugging me is that I want to use a progress bar to show completion, and after the urlretrieve, the only thing's moving is the progressbar, GUI just become unresponsive. I know that's something to do with threading but I'm really new at this. Can someone give me a hint?

The idea is at main frame I get search result from a site, and give the result to this `DownloadListingFrame`, it then generates buttons and `staticText` on the fly. The problem was after click download button, progressbar updates as file's being download, but other than that the whole app hangs.  After reading someone else's code from other example, I thought I put the `doDownload` function in a thread and executed it, it acts the same as was not using threading...

```py
class DownloadListingFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    data = ''

    def __init__( self, parent, result ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u'result', pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.statusbar.SetFieldsCount(3)

        self.progessBar = wx.Gauge(self.statusbar, -1, style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL|wx.GA_SMOOTH)
        rect = self.statusbar.GetFieldRect(1)
        self.progessBar.SetPosition((rect.x+2, rect.y+2 ))
        self.progessBar.SetSize((rect.width, rect.height-4))

        buttonPos = 20
        for item in result:
            label = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, item, wx.Point( 120 ,buttonPos+2 ), wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            button = wx.Button(self, id=-1,label=u'Download', pos=(20, buttonPos))
            buttonPos = buttonPos + 30
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda x: self.Downloader(item, result[item]), button)

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )


    def progressUpdate(self, blockCount, blockSize, totalSize):
        progressSoFar = int((float(blockCount) * float(blockSize) / float(totalSize)) * 100)
        self.progessBar.SetValue(progressSoFar)

    def doDownloade(self, realAddress, saveAsFilename):
        urllib.urlretrieve(realAddress, saveAsFilename, self.progressUpdate)

    def Downloader(self, title, url):
        saveAsPath = wx.DirDialog(self, u"save to...")
        if saveAsPath.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            realAddress = self.getRealAddress(url)
            saveAsFilename = os.path.join(saveAsPath.GetPath(), title + os.path.splitext(realAddress)[1])
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.doDownloade(realAddress, saveAsFilename))
            thread.setDaemon(True)
            thread.start()

    def getRealAddress(self, url):
        import httplib
        siteUrl = 'www.yyets.com'
        httpConnection = httplib.HTTPConnection(siteUrl)
        httpConnection.request("GET", url)
        resp = httpConnection.getresponse()
        realAddress = resp.getheaders()[6][1]
        return realAddress

    def __del__( self ):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the command:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=self.doDownloade(realAddress, saveAsFilename))
```

it first runs `self.doDownloade(realAddress, saveAsFilename)` and then passes the return value of this (which will be `None`) as the target.

Instead you want:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=self.doDownloade, args=(realAddress, saveAsFilename))
```

Note, here, I've passed in the **function** `self.doDownloade`, and then `thread` will call this with the agrs that you gave it when you call `thread.start`.

By the way, you can also do this with a `wx.Timer`.  I usually find this to be the better tool for gauges since it's easier and you can control how often the gauge is updated and therefore how much resources are used for the gauge.  The main wxPython demo's gauge example uses a wx.Timer is you want a good starting point.

Comment: Great.  Also see my new note at the end on using wx.Timer.